# Is there a variable for the file you open the CMD file with?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My CMD file:
`java -jar unluac.jar unluac.lua > unluac_decompiled.lua`

So in my CMD file, I have to manually change the name of the file I want unluac(.jar) to decompile. Now what I want is to be able to say something like this:

`java -jar unluac.jar [var].lua > [var]_decompiled.lua` where VAR would be the file i drag onto the CMD file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drag-and-drop a file onto one with a cmd extension, the name of the dropped file is passed as the first parameter.  So, assuming this will always be files with an "lua" extension, you could do:

```
@echo off
java -jar unluac.jar %1 > %~n1%_dec.%~x1%
```

Comment: Sometimes it'll also be a file with an extension called "dnax" (literally a renamed Lua file).

Would it be easier to keep two scripts? One for each file type or is there a way for it to check the file type too that'd not be too hard?

Comment: Well, that substitution won't do anything if the name is not found, so you could just add a second line saying `set X=%X:.dnax=_dec.dnax%`.

Comment: @BeyondCarl, please be aware that your code would be better using a single line, ```@"P:\athTo\java.exe" -jar "L:\ocationOf\unluac.jar" "S:\ourceDir\%~1.lua" 1>"D:\estinationDir\%~1_decompiled.lua"```.

Comment: That's a good modification.  I'll take it.

Comment: Thank you!
Now I have a follow-up question

I made a reg file so if I right-click on a file and click "unluac" it activates the script. However, that doesn't seem to work as it seems like it doesn't pick up the file. Is it because the file I right-click isn't passed as the first parameter?

Comment: If you used `ShellNew` or `OpenWithList`, then the names should be passed automatically.  You may need to add "%1" to your registry line to represent the file name.